# How to make a total of Listview subitems

Tags: vb6

Using Listview

How to make a total of subitems in the listview

Listview

```
ID Name 01 02 03 04 05 Total(A) Total(B)

001 Rajan A B A A B 3 2
002 Kumar B B   B A 1 3
.....
```

`Note`: In list view column header increase or decrease according to user input, sometimes
column header will be `ID Name 01 .... 18 Total(A) Total(B)`.  Column header will not be a constant

In that case, How to make a total of subitems from 01 to totalcolumns - 2 `'Taking the value for calcualation before Total(A) Total(B)`

Any idea's and suggestion..?

Comment: @Gopal: Any reason you're now posting under a different name?

Comment: Oh, I see, you were [suspended](http://stackoverflow.com/users/128071/gopal)

Comment: @Deanna The same type of questions, written in the exact same style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply total up the values as you assign them to the listview row. There is nothing in the ListView that will do this automatically for you.